# How to install o2 and keychain into my QT-Quick Project

Tags: c++, qt, oauth, cmake

my little problem is as such.

I have a new qt-quick project open, I have downloaded 2 libraries to help my program post to twitter.

https://github.com/pipacs/o2 - lib to help me post to twitter
https://github.com/frankosterfeld/qtkeychain - o2's dependency(helps store and encrypts incoming keys, and info.

I have no idea how to **include them into my project.**
I tried including the .pri file in my .pro file, adding the directories by right clicking the main project, and including the directories in my .pro.

I tried looking up how to do it, but it's not a .dll, its not a .lib file.  It's just headers, .cpp's, .pri files and a couple of cmakes.

Info on my build -> Windows 8.1 / Qt 5.9 -> installed with mingw, and added cmake.

Can someone try to install these libraries and tell me how to include them?

Comment: "Can someone try to install these libraries and tell me how to include them?" - probably not. But you could try to tell us more about what *you* tried and especially what errors you got when you tried to follow the instructions given by those libraries.

Comment: Well I can seem to now get it somewhat included but these errors pop up.C:\sandbox\test\loadr\o2-master\src\o2skydrive.cpp:51: error: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN10O0BaseAuth11openBrowserERK4QUrl'

Comment: @JesperJuhl I included the .pri's.  but for some reason most of the files come up as undefined.  Once I include the pri's in the .pro, what do I do next?